# How to set time picker only set time from 8:30 am to 5:30 pm in bootstrap-material-datetimepicker.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, material-design

I am using a time picker from material style. I am using this library(https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-material-datetimepicker/2.7.1/js/bootstrap-material-datetimepicker.js)

I want to set time picker from 8:30 am to 5:30 pm. User can't select any time out of this range. and that time should be disable in the time picker. User have to select a time between the time rang that I have set before.

Is this possible to do. using this library. Hope I have explained well and sorry for my bad English.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, changing the code within libraries is bad practice considering when you update the library to the newest version, you will lose any updates to the code from your previous version.

But this is simply a quick fix. Try changing 581 & 582 to

```
if(!checkHour && !checkMinute) {
   _minDate.hour(8);
   _minDate.minute(30);

   _date.hour(0);
   _date.minute(0);
}
```

same with lines 621 & 622

```
if(!checkTime && !checkMinute) {
   _maxDate.hour(17);
   _maxDate.minute(30);

   _date.hour(0);
   _date.minute(0);
}
```

Let me know how that goes!

Comment: Hi,Thanks for your reply. But it's not working with me. I did the same that you said. But There is no action in the browser. Still I can select all the time.

Comment: Did you got my point. Only user can select the in the rang that I have set before. user can't select anytime out of the range.